# Is the free group of rank 2 a subgroup of an infinite product of finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, amenability

I want to find an example of a non-amenable infinite product on amenable groups. My idea is to show that the free group of rank 2 is a subgroup of an infinite product of finite groups.

But I'm not really sure if it is true, and if it is, I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group is a subgroup of an infinite product of finite groups if (and only if) it is residually finite (i.e., no element is in the kernel of every homomorphism to a finite quotient group), as then it embeds in the product of all of its finite quotients. And free groups are residually finite.

Comment: Thanks ! I found some proofs that the free group is residually finite, but none show that your definition is equivalent to the fact that residually finite groups are subgroups of an infinte product of finite groups. Do you have a reference that prove this? Also, is there a non-trivial construction of this embedding for the free group ?

Comment: @Billy: it's an exercise to prove the equivalence, you should better think about it than looking for a reference.